# Aiogram 3 error_handler

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram-3.x, python-3.11

Есть такой хендлер

```
@error_router.error()
async def error_handler(event: ErrorEvent, state: FSMContext):
    await state.clear()

    if event.update.callback_query:
        await event.update.callback_query.answer()
        user_id = event.update.callback_query.from_user.id
        message = event.update.callback_query.message
    else:
        user_id = event.update.message.from_user.id
        message = event.update.message

    text = f'‍♂️ Упс... Что-то пошло не так.'
    markup = await gen_main_keyboard()

    await message.answer(text=text, reply_markup=markup, disable_web_page_preview=True)

    logger.critical(f'HANDLED ERROR | User <{user_id}> | {type(event.exception)} | {event.exception}')
```

Но проблема в том, что исключения не информативны. Есть ли вариант увидеть весь трайсбек в логах? Для логирования использую loguru.